# 404 - NOT FOUND in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm new to laravel and I've just installed the package on a local server.
I used php artisan serve to open the app
I made a simple route to test:

```php
Route::get('a', function () {
    return 'hi there';
});
```

but when I try to open this route I got 404 not found.

Comment: You're getting a 404 at `http://localhost:8000/a`?

Comment: yes. only the welcome page works

Comment: you may check the route list first: `php artisan route:list`

Comment: ok I figure it out I reinstalled the package using globally laravel installer